# When should I use a data source (protocol) vs setting the classes data on a property or on init?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, datasource

I've seen a data source on a ton of Apple's code; UITableView, UICollectionView, etc.

I am making a custom view which does not use the view reuse like my mentioned examples do.  Should I just set the data in the init method/using a property, or should I make a data source protocol on my custom view and get the data right when I want it from the client objects?  Or should I do some other thing I don't know about...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it depends.

If your view is presenting a lot of information and optimization techniques are needed to perform smoothly, then a dataSource delegate pattern should be used. If it's just a handful of small bits of data that needs to be displayed, just use properties/init.

`UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are heavily optimized views that **do a lot** to keep smooth scrolling performance. They can also present a large amount of data, which might not be practical to have all loaded in memory.

On the other hand, something like `UILabel` doesn't usually present a lot of information, so it uses properties to configure the data it needs to display.

Comment: Great, so on the view I'm currently working on I will have only 3 or four different single pieces of data that I'll need, so I'll likely not use a datasource protocol.  Maybe I'll change the question a little bit so you can fit in an answer to this, but if a view is not using view reuse, would you ever use a datasource protocol?

Comment: It's generally a good rule of thumb, but it doesn't necessarily require it. Using a DataSource abstracts the data structure that is needed to present the information (e.g. using NSFetchedResultsController instead of an array)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom view, usually parameters are set in `-initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method, that is called for a UIView only once.

But what if somewhere later you'll need to update smith of them?
 In that case i'd make an `updateView` method, that can be called from another classes and make any changes.

All values that can be changed make a local variables in order to access them in that method.